# No database provider .Net Core Angular app

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build my database using .NET Core 2.2 and Angular and have run across this error:

```
No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.
```

I have a default constructor in my `ApplicationDbContext` class.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> opts) : base()
        {
        }
}
```

My program cs looks okay to me:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(SetUpConfiguration)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();

        private static void SetUpConfiguration(WebHostBuilderContext ctx, IConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Sources.Clear();
            builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }
    }
```

And my startup registers the db:

```
private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        public Startup(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(cfg => {
                cfg.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("LevanaConnectionString"));
            });

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing the options into the base constructor:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> opts) : base(opts) // <-- this
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As we can see at the first message:
"If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext."

You're using "AddDbContext" at "ConfigureServices" class, but don't pass the "DbContextOptions" for the base constructor of "DbContext" at "ApplicationDbContext".

You can try this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> opts) : base(opts)
        {
        }
}
```